# Plot f(X, Y) with multiple parameters in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have pretty specific task here. Lets say I have  function of 5 variables. I want to make a 3d plot, where Ill take 2 variables as variables and 3 variables as fixed parameters. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

import numpy

#desired function is for example f(x, y, {a,b,c}) = x*a/((y+b)*(y+c))
a = 3
b = 8.5
c = 3.1
x = [i for i in range(-10,10,1)]
y = x

X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)

#this part of code is wrong
Z = X*a / ((Y+b)*(Y+c))
```

Lets plot it as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764088/python3plot-fx-y-preferably-using-matplotlib).

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
surf = ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride = 5, cstride = 5, 
       cmap = matplotlib.cm.jet)
fig.colorbar(surf)
plt.show()
```

Thank you for any hints or helps!

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: Ah sorry my code didnt work for me, but it works in another python distribution, so its probably version issue.

Comment: How did it not work? Add all this information to the question itself, don't post it in the comments. #1) We are not mind readers here. #2) Your question should be valid on its own, without comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error on `ax1` which is undefined.
This edited code should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import numpy

#desired function is for example f(x, y, {a,b,c}) = x*a/((y+b)*(y+c))
a = 3
b = 8.5
c = 3.1
x = [i for i in range(-10,10,1)]
y = x

X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X*a / ((Y+b)*(Y+c))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride = 5, cstride = 5, \
       cmap = matplotlib.cm.jet)

fig.colorbar(surf)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I missed it completely. Thx a lot!